# liquibase behavior when SSH session is closed

Tags: mysql, ssh, liquibase

I was running a `liquibase update` in a server through SSH. As it was taking a very long time and I forgot to use `screen`, the SSH session was terminated.

Then I SSH'd again and I `ps -A | grep liquibase`, and there was the liquibase process. Also my tables were still locked.

So what's the behavior of liquibase when the SSH session is closed? Does it keep working, or does it stay in a strange limbo state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a terminal closes, it sends the signal `SIGHUP` to all processes spawned by this terminal.

The `SIGHUP` signal can be caught by Java applications and apparently this is what liquibase is doing. Having a look at the Sourcecode, it seems that if a `SIGHUP` is caught, liquibase is trying to rollback the transaction, which can take some time and can keep databases locked.

Source Code at:
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/sdk/supplier/database/AllDatabases.java

Relevant code starting with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() { ... }
```

Note that `SIGKILL` (which could not be handled by the process) is NOT being sent to the processes when the terminal closes.